# Android FadeIn / FadeOut upon scrolling the webview

Tags: android, scroll, webview

I have a webview and i want to and i have added a gradient effect on bottom of webview, i want to fade this effect when user scrolls to bottom, and show it again when user start scrolling up.

```
webView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            int scrollY = termsTextView.getScrollY();

           float alpha = 1 - ((float)(scrollY +  webView.getHeight()) / totalHeight);
            gradientView.setAlpha(alpha);

        }


    });
```

apparently when user has already scrolled to bottom, scrollY + height should be equal to totalHeight of webView, but it is not.

I can not understand why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do it by using getContentHeight i.e.

```
                int totalHeight =(int) (webView.getContentHeight() * webTextView.getScale());
```